# Greenrobot EventBus sticky events priorities?

Tags: event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

Since Greenrobot EventBus events order [is not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605322/is-greenrobot-eventbus-sticky-events-order-guaranteed) by default is there any chance to set sticky events priorities to make the right order? I need to restore events order somehow after listener unregistered/registrered for screen rotation (activity recreation).

Comment: I believe event priorities and event cancellation is the right way to do it.